# Why it is forbidden to use 'out' keyword in generics if a method excepts the type parameter as a parameter?

Tags: kotlin, generics, covariance, contravariance

I'm looking for an example that can cause a problem when using **out** in class declaration and the class has a method that get the parameter type as argument.

Also I'm looking for an example that can cause a problem when using **in** in class declaration and the parameter type is a **var** member of the class?
I think that i will be able to understand the rules only by examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose these are the classes we are working with:

```
open class Animal

class Cat: Animal() {
    fun meow() = println("meow")
}
```

If we create a class like this with covariant `out` type and the compiler allowed us to use the type as a function parameter:

```
class Foo<out T: Animal> {
    private var animal: T? = null

    fun consumeValue(x: T) { // NOT ALLOWED
        animal = x
    }

    fun produceValue(): T? {
        return animal
    }
}
```

Then if you do this, it will be lead to an impossible situation where we are trying to call `meow` on an Animal that doesn't have a `meow` function:

```
val catConsumer = Foo<Cat>()
val animalConsumer: Foo<Animal> = catConsumer // upcasting is valid for covariant type
animalConsumer.consumeValue(Animal())
catConsumer.produceValue()?.meow() // can't call `meow` on plain Animal
```

And if we create a class like this with contravariant `in` type and the compiler allowed us to use the type as a return value:

```
class Bar<in T: Animal>(private val library: List<T>) {
    fun produceValue(): T  { // NOT ALLOWED
        return library.random()
    }
}
```

Then if you do this, it will lead to the compiler impossibly casting a return type to a subtype.

```
val animalProducer: Bar<Animal> = Bar(List(5) { Animal() })
val catProducer: Bar<Cat> = animalProducer // downcasting is valid for contravariant type
catProducer.produceValue().meow() // can't call `meow` on plain Animal
```

A property has a getter which is just like a function that returns a value, and a `var` property additionally has a setter, which is just like a function that takes a parameter. So `val` properties are not compatible with contravariance (`in`) and `var` properties are not compatible with contravariance or covariance (`out`). Private properties aren't encumbered by these restrictions because within the class's inner workings, the type is invariant. All the class can know about its own type is its bounds. Variance just affects how the class can be cast (viewed) by the outside world.

So an example with `val` is enough to show why any property is incompatible with contravariance. You could replace `val` with `var` below and it would be no different.

```
class Bar<in T: Animal>(
    val animal: T // NOT ALLOWED
)

val animalProducer: Bar<Animal> = Bar(Animal())
val catProducer: Bar<Cat> = animalProducer // downcasting is valid for contravariant type
catProducer.animal.meow() // can't call `meow` on plain Animal
```

Comment: I guess `Animal` and `Cat` makes better examples than `Child` and `Parent` :D

Comment: @Tenfour04, thanks a lot. But can you please refer to the var issue with the in keyword?

Comment: `class Foo<out T: Cat> {
    fun consumeValue(x: T) { // NOT ALLOWED
        x.meow()
    }
}`
shouldn't it be <out T: Animal> instead of T:cat?? otherwise how can you create a Foo<Animal>?

Comment: I understand well all your explanation (since it's very exhaustive)... Only the first example (the one we are talking about now) is a little bit blur.. Is there a valid way to illustrate the problem when using `out` and the class has a method that gets the parameter type? sorry for bothering but it is important for me to understand the issue once and forever

Comment: The Foo example was the simplest I could come up with. If the type has to be a subtype of Cat, then the consuming function can assume a T passed to it is a Cat, and call Cat-unique functions on it. If we then make `T` an `out` parameter, this assumption is no longer valid, because an `out` type can be upcast to a supertype.

Comment: Another way to put it is to say, "out means it's safe to treat supertypes of T as T". That's why a `Foo<Cat>` can be cast to `Foo<Animal>`. But if our function takes T as a parameter, this statement about safety is false. An Animal doesn't have a `meow()` function so it cannot be safely treated as a Cat. If we were only producing Cats, the safety statement would be valid, because you would just be casting Cats to Animals when returning them.

Comment: @Tenfour04 OP is right in the sense that with `Foo<out T : Cat>` you can't actually declare anything of type `Foo<Animal>`, so the example doesn't really work here, although the concept still holds.

Comment: The OP is frustrated that he can't find by himself an example for this situation :)  Thank you mates!

Comment: Oh, I see. @Joffrey is right. My example doesn't work. Although upcasting is allowed for covariant types, you can't upcast past the type bound, so you can't cast `Foo<Cat>` to `Foo<Animal>` like I did. A proper example is a little more complicated. See the update.

Answer (score 3):

#### Small reminder about variance

When you have a generic class `G<T>` (parameterized type), the variance is about defining a relationship between the hierarchy of the types `G<T>` for different `T`s, and the hierarchy of the different `T`s themselves.

For instance, if child class `C` extends a parent `P` then:

- does `List<C>` extend `List<P>`? (`List<T>` would be covariant in `T`)
- or the reverse? (contravariant)
- or is there no relationship between `List<C>` and `List<P>`? (invariant).

#### Example

Now, consider `List<out T>`, which means that `List` is *covariant* in `T`.
As we've just seen, declaring list as such means that the following holds: "if `C` extends `P`, then `List<C>` extends `List<P>`".

Let's assume the following class declarations here:

```kotlin
open class Parent {
    fun doParentStuff()
}

class Child : Parent() {
    fun doChildStuff()
}
```

The covariance of `List<out T>` means that this is possible:

```kotlin
val listOfChild: List<Child> = listOf<Child>(Child(), Child())
// this is ok because List is covariant in T (out T)
// so List<Child> is a subtype of List<Parent>, and can be assigned to listOfParent
val listOfParent: List<Parent> = listOfChild
```

So what would happen if we could declare a method in the `List` class that accepts a parameter `T`?

```kotlin
class List<out T> {
    fun add(element: T) {
        // I can guarantee here that I have an instance of T, right?
    }
}
```

The rules of most languages (including Kotlin) state that if a method accepts a parameter of type `T`, you can technically get an instance of `T` **or any subclass of T** (this is the point of subclassing), but you have at least all the API of T available to you.

But remember that we declared `List<out T>`, which means I can do:

```kotlin
val listOfChild: List<Child> = listOf<Child>(Child(), Child())
// this is ok because List is covariant in T (out T)
val listOfParent: List<Parent> = listOfChild

// listOfChild and listOfParent point to the same list instance
// so here we are effectively adding a Parent instance to the listOfChild
listOfParent.add(Parent()) 

// oops, the last one is not an instance of Child, bad things will happen here
// we could fail right here at runtime because Parent cannot be cast to Child
val child: Child = listOfChild.last

// even worse, look at what looks possible, but is not:
child.doChildThing()
```

Here you can see that from within the `List<Child>` instance, we actually could receive an instance of `Parent` which is not a subclass of `Child` in a method that had declared a parameter of type `Child`.

Comment: i think your post can serve me with the one example that is missing me